# Hadoop Webhdfs Delete option over Amazon EMR failed

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, emr, webhdfs

i'm trying to see if delete option works over webhdfs :

```
http://ec2-ab-cd-ef-hi.compute-1.amazonaws.com:14000/webhdfs/v1/user/barak/barakFile.csv?op=DELETE&user.name=hadoop
```

but i get an error:

```
{"RemoteException":{"message":"Invalid HTTP GET operation [DELETE]",
"exception":"IOException","javaClassName":"java.io.IOException"}}
```

This file has all privilege ( 777 ) .

```
[hadoop@ip-172-99-9-99 ~]$ hadoop fs -ls hdfs:///user/someUser
Found 2 items
-rwxrwxrwx 1 hadoop hadoop 344 2015-12-10 08:33 hdfs:///user/someUser/someUser.csv
```

what else should i check for allowing in order to allow delete option over Amazon EMR WEBHDFS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the needed privileges for a file but didn't have all the needed privileges for the directory. changing permission for the entire Path solved it.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use curl -i -X command like this

```
curl -i -X DELETE "http://ec2-**-**-**-***.compute-1.amazonaws.com:14000/webhdfs/v1/user/hadoop/hdfs-site.xml?op=DELETE&user.name=hadoop"
```

Comment: curl doesn't helps me, i need to do it with Http Request command.

Comment: As per my knowledge you cannot do it using http